# Html linked to another html

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation bar on my pages and im having trouble moving from one html doc to another. Its weird to word so i drew a picture ( [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOlj1.png) )
Both html documents are within the same folder and i have cleared the cache just in case. The problem is i can move from 'mainpage' to 'about' page but not in reverse. **Any tips or comments?**

[Folder of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WRS4.png)

Main page

```
<div class="icon-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu
</div>

<div class="menu">
    <div class="icon-close">
        <img src="images/close_icon.png">
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="mainpage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

About page

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="icon-close">
        <img src="images/close_icon.png">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="mainpage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li>
            <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: what happens when you click on mainpage from about? Is it possible that your main page is not called `mainpage.html`?

Comment: it does not go back and it is called 'mainpage.html'. 'mainpage.html' to 'about.html' works fine but 'about.html' to 'mainpage.html' does not work

Comment: what happens when you click mainpage from the main page?

Comment: it stays on mainpage.html

Comment: By "it does not go back", do you mean the page does not change at all? or do you get an error page?

Comment: no error, nothing

Comment: So it's not a blank page. Do you have some javascript running on the page? Maybe an event handler is preventing it?

Comment: yep, it was the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine. Possible errors are that filename of mainpage may have an error or if you are using any framework, it may produce some error. 
This code is working fine in plain html without any css or js. So provide more information in case.